# Azure DevOps - Nuget pack packages test projects

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget

I have a solution with .NET Core 3.1 projects and those include test projects (xUnit). And I created a pipeline in the Azure DevOps which builds Nuget packages. And for some reason it creates packages for test projects too, even when they have

> ```
> <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
> ```

How can I exclude project from being packaged with Nuget?

The pipeline uses Windows 2019 agent, .NET Core 3.1, latest Nuget, NuGet pack and NuGet push tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jKlaus suggested, instead of using a single pack task with `**/*.csproj` pattern, you should use multiple pack tasks - 1 per project. For example, for a particular project, you will have this step:

```yaml
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Pack ProjectName'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
```

And there will be others for different projects.

Comment: If memory serves I believe most of the filter languages allow for exclusion as well.  So you can do something like.. "!*Tests*.csproj"  I may be mis-remembering that though.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the NuGet Task through the Gui, it provides the solution to your problem:

`**\*.csproj;!**\*.Tests.csproj`

Your Nuget command should look something like this:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**\*.csproj;!**\*.Tests.csproj'
    versioningScheme: #yourversioningscheme
```

[image: screenshot from AzDO]

If the solution you are building has projects you don't wish to pack then you would have to manually reference the projects you wish to package.

`**\Foo.csproj;`

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically target the project to package with every step I've ever used.  I think IsPackable is only respected by dotnet, not nuget.

Comment: What do you mean "You can specifically target the project to package with every step I've ever used" ??

Comment: oh, I got it! Thanks. Can you update your answer just to make it clear (preferably with example). Or I can add my own.

Comment: I use a classic editor, so there's no manual. ok, I'll post my own answer.
Besides, dotnet CLI doesn't work as expected in my pipeline. That's why I had to switch to nuget tasks

Comment: At the end of the day whether you're using the classic editor or new yaml builds they all just result in the execution of CLI commands.  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/dotnet-commands